# Стили для html-кода внутри php

Tags: php, html, css

Внутри php-кода пишу следующее:

```
echo "<div id = 'snake'>
             <p>snake</p>
           </div>";
```

В стилях прописываю:

```
#snake p {
  color: red;
}
```

И цвет не меняется!

При этом, когда пишу стили внутри тега, все отлично работает.
Такое ощущение, что из файла css-кода не видно html элементов внутри php, при этом со всеми элементами, которые не находятся в блоке php кода все нормально.

Comment: Откройте инструменты разработчика и проверьте

Comment: php-код тут при чём? Проверяйте, что браузеру пришёл правильный html-код и что он смог скачать правильный css-файл и что этот стиль не перекрывается другими стилями

Comment: Откройте исходный код страницы и посмотрите, выводятся стили или нет. Видимо у Вас стили не выводятся в браузер

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<div id='snake'><p>snake</p></div>";

#snake p {
  color: red;
}
```